# I need to know what piano chords I am singing

Tags: theory, chords, songwriting

I am a songwriter but I do not play piano. I can pick my melody out with one finger, but that’s it. Is there an app or some way to record myself singing a song and have it determine the piano chords for me?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not yet,but in the future...

Problem is, given two or three notes from part of a melody may - or may not - fit to one chord. Often there are several choices, which is one reason most melodies can be, and are, particularly in jazz, re-harmonised. Nothing wrong with that, except the options grow in number as any melody progresses. A programmed app would have to be aware of all the options, and get pretty complicated to use. Or be simple and give 'cast-iron' harmonies which at best could be turbid.

As a songwriter, you know words and how they fit together, and know how to fit melodies to those words. You're more than half way there! And only you will know what actual chords you want to fit to those melodies.Right now, you may not know what a chord may be called, but I'm certain when you hear a particular chord over a particular line, you'll say yes or no to it.

Seems like the next step is to grab an instrument, probably a teacher, and explore possibilities of harmony. Piano or guitar are the best options, and will expand your palette exponentially, at the same time making you into a far far better writer.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. To make a chord you need 3 or more (or at least 2) notes. An app may be able to transcribe the melody you're singing, but it will be up to you to choose the other notes to create a chord.

If you learn some basic chords, maybe enough to play a few songs in similar styles to the ones you want to write. then you should be able to make a decent start at building chord progressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to write lyrics and melody, you have written  your song. Harmony (chords) actually fall into the category of arranging the song for performance. If you are not a musician you have the option of studying to become one, or finding another musician who can help you develop your song. Another option is to look for an educated arranger who can make short work and turn your song into sheet music that almost anyone can read and play. I enjoy the study of harmony and music theory in general, and I like to encourage others to study it and grow to understand it. Each new thing I learn seems to help me better understand and appreciate my own accomplishments musically.